# How to add polygon to 3D Map in r rayshader?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, rayshader

I am new to **geo spatial data** and just manage to plot in small bits & pieces by looking at few articles on web.

I am trying to **plot polygon boundaries** on the **3D plot** which I have built using **rayshader** package but facing **issues** with **displaying polygon boundaries** on top.

Shape file used is `2011_Dist.shp` which can be downloaded from [Shapefile Github link](https://github.com/datameet/maps/tree/master/Districts/Census_2011)

**Code I have tried:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(elevatr)
library(raster)
library(rayshader)
library(osmdata)
```

```
# read districts shape file
ind_distirct_shp <- sf::st_read("local path/2011_Dist.shp")
ind_distirct_shp
```

```
# filter State
delhi_district_shp <- ind_distirct_shp %>% 
                       sf::st_as_sf() %>% 
                       filter(ST_NM %in% c("NCT of Delhi"))
```

```
# this shows the polygon boundaries that I need on top of map
plot(delhi_district_shp)
```

[image]

```
# download elevation data for State Delhi
delhi_raster <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(delhi_district_shp, z = 10, clip = "location")
```

```
# convert to matrix
delhi_mat <- raster_to_matrix(delhi_raster)
```

```
# 3D plot using Rayshader
delhi_mat %>%
  
  height_shade(texture = grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("#9a133d","orange","red","purple"
                                                       ))(256)) %>%
  plot_3d(heightmap = delhi_mat, 
          windowsize = c(800,800), # c(800*wr,800*hr) 
          solid = FALSE, 
          zscale = 1,
          phi = 90, 
          zoom = .6, 
          theta = 0,
          shadowcolor = "grey50",  
          linewidth = 6,
          background = "white",
          solidlinecolor = "#013b39")
```

[image]

**Issue:** Now when I try to Modify this to add `polygon lines` it doesn't work.

```
polygon_layer = generate_polygon_overlay(delhi_district_shp, extent = extent(delhi_raster),
                                    heightmap = delhi_mat) # , palette="grey30"

polygon_layer
```

```
delhi_mat %>%
  
  height_shade(texture = grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("#9a133d","orange","red","purple"
                                                       ))(256)) %>% 
  add_overlay(polygon_layer) %>% 
  
  plot_3d(heightmap = delhi_mat, 
          windowsize = c(800,800), # c(800*wr,800*hr) 
          solid = FALSE, 
          zscale = 1,
          phi = 90, 
          zoom = .6, 
          theta = 0,
          shadowcolor = "grey50",  
          linewidth = 6,
          background = "white",
          solidlinecolor = "#013b39")
```

[image]

It should have been polygon lines on top of the Orange 3D map but it didn't work as I expected.

2. I also tried with Rayshder's tyler website example https://www.tylermw.com/adding-open-street-map-data-to-rayshader-maps-in-r/

```
library(osmdata)

osm_bbox = c(extent(delhi_raster)[3],extent(delhi_raster)[1],extent(delhi_raster)[4],extent(delhi_raster)[2])
osm_bbox
```

```
raster_polygon_boundary <- osmdata::opq(osm_bbox) %>% 
  add_osm_feature("highway") %>%  # "admin_level" 
  osmdata_sf()

raster_polygon_boundary
```

Output:

```
Object of class 'osmdata' with:
                 $bbox : 76.8425681832661,28.4030759258059,77.347719586084,28.8793200072187
        $overpass_call : The call submitted to the overpass API
                 $meta : metadata including timestamp and version numbers
           $osm_points : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 0 points
            $osm_lines : NULL
         $osm_polygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 0 polygons
       $osm_multilines : NULL
    $osm_multipolygons : NULL
```

I am getting **0 polygons & lines** above so I wont't be able to add any `polygon` on top of **3D plot**.

How can I fix this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `alphalayer` to `add_overlay(polygon_layer,alphalayer = .6)` helped even though it worked but still transparency is not working perfectly. It is causing some `whiteness` in the plot. If anyone else has better answer or way to improve it then please feel free to share.

```
delhi_mat %>%
  
  height_shade(texture = grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("#9a133d","orange","red","purple"
                                                       ))(256)) %>% 
  add_overlay(polygon_layer,alphalayer = .6) %>% 
  
  add_overlay(generate_label_overlay(delhi_district_shp, extent = extent(delhi_raster),
                                     text_size = 5, point_size = 1, 
                                     halo_color = "white",halo_expand = 5, 
                                     seed=1,
                                     heightmap = delhi_mat, data_label_column = "DISTRICT")) %>% 
  
  plot_3d(heightmap = delhi_mat, 
          windowsize = c(800,800), # c(800*wr,800*hr) 
          solid = FALSE, 
          zscale = .7,
          phi = 90, 
          zoom = .6, 
          theta = 0,
          shadowcolor = "grey50",  
          linewidth = 6,
          background = "white",
          solidlinecolor = "#013b39")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you're looking for by creating a custom color (white, 100% transparent) to fill the polygon with:

```
polygon_layer = generate_polygon_overlay(delhi_district_shp, 
                                         extent = extent(delhi_raster),
                                         heightmap = delhi_mat,
                                         palette = rgb(0,0,0,0)) # R,G,B,alpha
```